# Numpy pad zeroes of given size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, zero-padding

I have read most related questions here, but I cannot seem to figure out how to use `np.pad` in this case. Maybe it is not meant for this particular problem.

Let's say I have a list of Numpy arrays. Every array is the same length, e.g. 2. The list itself has to be padded to be e.g. 5 arrays and can be transformed into a numpy array as well. The padded elements should be arrays filled with zeroes. As an example

```
arr = [array([0, 1]), array([1, 0]), array([1, 1])]
expected_output = array([array([0, 1]), array([1, 0]), array([1, 1]), array([0, 0]), array([0, 0])])
```

The following seems to work, but I feel there must be a better and more efficient way. In reality this is run hundreds of thousands if not millions of times so speed is important. Perhaps with `np.pad`?

```
import numpy as np

def pad_array(l, item_size, pad_size=5):
  s = len(l)

  if s < pad_size:
    zeros = np.zeros(item_size)
    for _ in range(pad_size-s):
      # not sure if I need a `copy` of zeros here?
      l.append(zeros)

  return np.array(l)

B = [np.array([0,1]), np.array([1,0]), np.array([1,1])]
AB = pad_array(B, 2)

print(AB)
```

Comment: Isn't the output just a two dimensional-array?

Comment: @DanielMesejo It is. (Shape 1xn.) I'm not sure why that's important, nor why you deleted your answer as that seemed fine. (Even though it could use some more explanation.)

Comment: What should happen if pad_size is less than the length of the input list?

Comment: In reality that cannot happen because pad_size is derived from the input data. So in such a case, just return the np.array variant.

Comment: For what are you using the `item_size` parameter? If all arrays are of the same size, you can get rid of that and just use the length of the first array like `zeros = np.zeros(len(l[0]))` here.

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ Good catch, I did that indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-write your function like this:

```
import numpy as np


def pad_array(l, item_size, pad_size=5):

    if pad_size < len(l):
        return np.array(l)

    s = len(l)
    res = np.zeros((pad_size, item_size))  # create an array of (item_size, pad_size)
    res[:s] = l  # set the first rows equal to the elements of l

    return res


B = [np.array([0, 1]), np.array([1, 0]), np.array([1, 1])]
AB = pad_array(B, 2)

print(AB)
```

**Output**

```
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 1.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

The idea is to create an array of zeroes and then fill the first rows with the values from the input list.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to pad zeros at the end of the axis 0, speaking in `numpy` terms. So what you need is,

```
output = numpy.pad(arr, ((0,2),(0,0)), 'constant')
```

The trick is the `pad_width` parameter, which you need to specify as `pad_width=((0,2),(0,0))` to get your expected output. This is you telling `pad()` to insert 0 padding at the beginning and 2 padding at the end of the axis 0, and to insert 0 padding at the beginning and 0 padding at the end of the axis 1. The format of `pad_width` is  `((before_1, after_1), … (before_N, after_N))` according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)

`mode='constant'` tells `pad()` to pad with the value specified by parameter `constant_values` which defaults to 0.